# "me's" when referring to another version of you?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, possessives, possessive-pronouns

Let's say I want to refer to a toy that I had when I was younger.  Would it be incorrect to say "young me's toy"?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the noun phrase *young me* to describe yourself in the past, then adding an apostrophe and *s* to form the possessive would be normal.

> *Young me* was quite precocious.
>   *Young me's* toys were all red.

---

Having said that, it's unusual to use *young me* in the first place. More typically, a variation would be used:

> When I was a child, all of my toys were red.

But I can see *young me* (and the possessive) being used in the context of fiction, for example, if you go back in time and meet yourself. In that situation, you'd have to differentiate between your current self and your *young* self in some way. It's not unreasonable to think of that wording being the chosen device.

Comment: It would likely be better to avoid `me's` and use something like "All the toys of the young me were red."

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, I too would add the definite article if I was talking about "the young me". "Young me" or "Young me's" as used in the OP seems very awkward even without the possessive s.

Comment: Your toys were a child?

Answer (score 0):

It seems grammatical, although it sounds weird unless it's meant humorously. But I have seen writers use the third-person when referring to themselves with such a construction, like *young Manar's toy.*